# Why can't I share index and base route model methods in ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

If I have a nested route like so

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("foo", {path: "/foos"}, function( {
    this.resource("bar", {path: "/:foo_id/bars"}, function() {
      this.resource("bazz", {path: "/:bar_id"});
    });
  });
});
```

When I launch into the app, I need a FooIndexRoute to load all the foo objects. Yet when I refresh at the very bottom route my FooIndexRoute isn't loaded so I'm forced to duplicate the model hook in my FooRoute

What am I doing wrong in the url structure that is forcing me to duplicate this effort?

Comment: Can't you place the loading of the objects into the FooRoute and in the FooIndexRoute just use this.modelFor("Foo") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that it works best when the base route (`foo`) is used to load the list of models and the index (`foo.index`) is used to display the list. This is an advantage because the `{{outlet}}` in the `foo` route will be initially filled with the `foo.index` view, but once you select the one you want to drill down into `foo`'s outlet will be be switched to the `bar` route's info. This preserves `foo`'s controller and model data through the nesting.

```
application
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── bazz
│   │   └── index
│   └── index
└── index
```

You can see that if you load data in the `foo.index` route, when you transition to the `bar` route, the nesting path now does not include `foo.index` which means it isn't easily accessible.

In child routes you can use `this.modelFor('foo')` to retrieve the `foo` route's model and either directly use it as the model or add it to the route's controller:

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

// use foo's model as the index's model
App.FooIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('foo');
  }
});

// this route has its own model, but also include foo's model
App.BarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'];
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('fooModel', this.modelFor('foo'));
  }
});
```

Here is a JSBin showing the nesting: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oxAluJI/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

The index route is a catch all route, it's only hit if you are hitting that resource and you haven't defined the default route. You should define the model hook right on the route name itself and ditch the index route.

AKA

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
   model: function....
})
```

If you want the index route to still exist, you can in the model hook for the index route use `return this.modelFor('foo');`. So you can avoid fetching the models twice etc.

Additionally in your deeper routes, if their models are just children of the parent routes, just use modelFor to get the parent model and filter out the appropriate item.

If you need a jsbin example let me know.

Comment: should the above "App.Foo" be instead "App.FooRoute" ?